# Problems with binaries when scraping

Tags: elixir

When scraping a Russian website with HTTPoison I get binaries I cannot decode, e.g. `<<206, 225, 237, 238, 226, 235, 229, 237, 238, 32, 50, 51, 32, 237, 238, 255, 225, 240, 255, 32, 226, 32, 49, 50, 58, 51, 53>>` for "Обновлено 23 ноября в 12:35". Is there some bitstring specifier for this?

Comment: The string seems to be encoded with Windows-1251.

Comment: Found a [library](https://github.com/woxtu/elixir-mbcs) for decoding Windows-1251.

Answer (score 1):

Found a [library](https://github.com/woxtu/elixir-mbcs) for decoding Windows-1251 and it worked.

Comment: Install elixir-mbcs but after running& i have error:
ex(1)> Mbcs.start
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function :mbcs.start/0 (module :mbcs is not available)
    :mbcs.start()

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by `{:iconv, "~> 1.0"}` https://hex.pm/packages/iconv

Add `{:iconv, "~> 1.0"}` to mix.exs. After `start iex -S mix`:

```
iex(4)> :application.start(:iconv)
:ok
iex(5)> :iconv.convert("windows-1251", "utf-8", <<205, 232, 230, 237, 232, 233, 32, 205, 238, 226, 227, 238, 240, 238, 228>>)
"Нижний Новгород"
```